# PHP secured login cookie, am I doing it right?

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication, php-password-hash

I'm pretty new to PHP/MYSQL, what I'm aiming at right now is creating a secure simple login cookie, here's what I did:

1. When a new user register, the script creates a random hashed (salted) string like this: a4c7be8b6426f34c13adc37ba69db2dd, and it's **saved in the database** as **"special cookie"**.
2. Each user has his own **"special cookie"**.
3. When the user attempt successfully to login, the script grabs his **special cookie** from the database and save it as **a cookie to the browser**.
4. In every page the script makes sure the user is logged in by comparing the saved cookie in the browser by the **"special cookies"** in the database.

is that secure enough?

BTW, I have another question, in PHP 5.5 is **password_hash()** alone secure enough ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: For `password_hash()` I specify `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` as the second argument so it uses that algorithm. As far as I know, it's fine to use like that alone (I believe it will generate its own salt, etc).
I'm no expert on this so YMMV!

Comment: `password_hash()` is secure by default. If you use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` it will automatically use the most secure algorithm available at the time, but you need to make sure your database will hold longer hashes. Read the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security is a great chapter in times of NSA.

There are different ways that may be considered "secure", here are some points you need to take care of. If one of these points is not true for your application, it might not be considered "secure".

- Do you have SSL enabled?
- Are the passwords stored hashed + salted in the database?
- Is the client able to change the cookie / session contents and use someone else's "secret" to take over the session?
- Can I brute force the "secret", password or username to gain access? (Limit requests per IP, CAPTCHA, ...)
- How often does the "secret" change, I'd suggest to change it on every request.
- Try to use public/private key encryption instead of symmetric hashing/encryption when possible.
- Use greater salt, found this: `<?php $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.'); ?>` for bcrypt

I think your applicatio is not secure unless the "special secret" changes on every request and cannot be used by a different client. Sessions are better in this case because their values get stored on the server (in most modern configurations) instead of plain in cookies on the client. Link each "special secret" to each client's session_id and change the keys every request.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you need to hash the cookie values, because session_id is hashed anyway and whenever you authenticate your user the session id will be assigned to the user and saved to a cookie.

you only need to store hash values of passwords in db for authentication.

Comment: I'm not using sessions, I'm using only cookies

Answer (score 0):

The login cookie you are describing is basically the same as the built in PHP sessions without the storage capability. Using a session would be simpler. In either case, you should change the value whenever the user logs in or out.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, A cookie must be tamper resistant(one can not change the cookie that the server saves into the browser), unforgeable, should not be able to be replayed and also it should be easy for the server to verify the validity of the cookie.

In your approach, the cookie is tamper resistant and unforgeable because the server creates it, stores it and compares the cookie value to verify its validity before considers a user as an already logged in user.

However, it does not address the other two properties. The cookie can be replayed since it doesn't include any information for the server to validate its freshness. (It is true that the browsers discard the expired cookies, but we can't always rely on that since the cookie is in the hands of the client who owns the browser.) On the other hand, server needs to store an additional value for each user for the purpose of maintaining cookies and each time a cookie is validated, a database search needs to be performed.

Let me suggest a better way to create a cookie authenticator which I learnt in my Information Security class.

You can create the cookie value in the format of: **username:time,HMAC(username:time)**

When generating the HMAC of (username:time) string, server uses a secret key only known to the server so that the hash value can not be tampered at the client side. 
When validating the cookie, server can first verify if the second value in the comma separated string of the cookie matches the HAMC of the first value generated using the secret key. After the hash is verified, it can verify if the cookie is not expired using the time information embedded in the cookie.

This way you do not have to store a special value for each user to verify the validity of his/her logged in session and also no need to do a database call at each verification.

Hope this provides some insights to your question.